# Crontab dont find/recognize path

Tags: ruby, macos, cron

I'm using a osx and I created a ruby script in the path: `/Users/diogo/workspace/outros/crawler_trf` with name `get_news.rb`

So I tried to execute it via crontab with the following line: `*/1 * * * * 'ruby /Users/diogo/workspace/outros/crawler_trf/get_news.rb' > /tmp/crawler_trf.out` and I've got the error: `/bin/sh: ruby /Users/diogo/workspace/outros/crawler_trf/get_news.rb: No such file or directory`

I really had searching for my answers for long but I didn't found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cron` is feeding your command:

```
'ruby /Users/diogo/workspace/outros/crawler_trf/get_news.rb' > /tmp/crawler_trf.out
```

to `/bin/sh` as-is but there is no `'ruby /Users/diogo/...'` command, there probably is a `ruby` command that can take `/Users/diogo/...` as an argument though so drop the quotes:

```
*/1 * * * * ruby /Users/diogo/workspace/outros/crawler_trf/get_news.rb > /tmp/crawler_trf.out
```

You might want to include the full path to `ruby` as well or at least make sure there's a `PATH` setting in your `crontab`.